# Convert an xml node to string

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm getting an xml answer from a server using jquery and I need to have one of its child nodes as a string to further work with it.
Here is my code:

```js
function pollServer(dataObject) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/server.php',
        data: dataObject,
        success: function (data) {
            $xmlDoc = $(data);
            $listen = $xmlDoc.find('listen');
            console.log($listen);
        },
        dataType: 'xml'
    });
}
```

I already tried using `(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(listen)` but that gives me an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work fine for XML:

```
var listen = $("listen", data)[0].outerHTML;
```